# Solr Did you mean , spelling suggestion not correct

Tags: solr

I use solr for my apps and i integrated the spellcheck component but i have some problem :
When I search a term "Women" that gives spelling suggestion "woven" 
another example search a term "pants" that gives spelling suggestion "pnt"

how do we stop these type of spelling suggestion

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you don't. If there's a spelling suggestion to be made, then Solr will return it. What you might choose to do is only return spelling suggestions when no results are returned from a search. Or at least that's what we do at my shop. This, of course, will require you to code up some logic in your app.